# Replace broken img with fallback picture

Tags: javascript, onerror

It's really simple: if the link to a pic is broken a backup link steps in. I've googled this and it should be straight forward but I can't get it working. I need to add it in Javascript and this is the line I've been trying to fix it with:

```
var issuePicFront = document.createElement("img");
issuePicFront.id = "first" + count;
issuePicFront.src = issues[count].images.imageFront;
issuePicFront.onerror="this.src=replacePic";
var replacePic = https://www.jordans.com/~/media/jordans%20redesign/no-image-found.ashx?h=275&la=en&w=275&hash=F87BC23F17E37D57E2A0B1CC6E2E3EEE312AAD5B
```

I still get `404 (Not found)`. According to the majority och the internetz this is the common solution but don't work for me.

Any clues to solve this?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [jQuery/JavaScript to replace broken images](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/92720/jquery-javascript-to-replace-broken-images)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should put quotes around the fallback URL (Assuming the rest of the code is working).

I would also suggest to change the error handler to a function, like this:

```
issuePicFront.onerror=function(e){
   var replacePic = '<URL>'
   this.src=replacePic;
};
```